# Java Refactor classes have same method

Tags: java, refactoring

Any suggestions for me to refactor the class, all the static methods are the same, only one of the variable `code` is different.

```
public class SuccessResponseBuilder {

    static ResponseCode code = ResponseCode.OK;

    public static <T> @NotNull ResponseBean build() {
        return ResponseBean.builder(code, null);
    }

    public static <T> ResponseBean build(T data) {
        return ResponseBean.builder(code, data);
    }
}
```

```
public class ErrorResponseBuilder {

    static ResponseCode code = ResponseCode.ERROR;

    public static <T> @NotNull ResponseBean build() {
        return ResponseBean.builder(code, null);
    }

    public static <T> ResponseBean build(T data) {
        return ResponseBean.builder(code, data);
    }
}
```

The client will used this way to get the result

`ErrorResponseBuilder.build(e.getMessage());`
`SuccessResponseBuilder.build("ok");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a flexible, clean approach. The main idea is creating an inner `Builder` class. The advantage is you can simply add a new `ResponseCode` without creating new class.

```java
public class ResponseBean {

    private final ResponseCode code;
    private Object data;

    private ResponseBean(ResponseCode code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    private ResponseBean(ResponseCode code, Object data) {
        this.code = code;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static Builder ok() {
        return new Builder(ResponseCode.OK);
    }

    public static Builder error() {
        return new Builder(ResponseCode.ERROR);
    }

    /* if you would like to create a new ResponseCode:
    public static Builder yourNewCode() {
        return new Builder(ResponseCode.NEW_CODE);
    }
    */

    public static class Builder {

        private final ResponseCode code;

        public Builder(ResponseCode code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
        
        public ResponseBean build() {
            return new ResponseBean(code);
        }

        public ResponseBean build(Object data) {
            return new ResponseBean(code, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
public void print() {
    ResponseBean okResponse = ResponseBean.ok().build("This is ok data");
    ResponseBean okResponseWithoutData = ResponseBean.ok().build();
    ResponseBean errorResponse = ResponseBean.error().build("This is error data");
    ResponseBean errorResponseWithoutData = ResponseBean.error().build();

    System.out.println(okResponse);
    System.out.println(okResponseWithoutData);
    System.out.println(errorResponse);
    System.out.println(errorResponseWithoutData);
}
```

Output will be

```java
ResponseBean(code=OK, data=This is ok data)
ResponseBean(code=OK, data=null)
ResponseBean(code=ERROR, data=This is error data)
ResponseBean(code=ERROR, data=null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! With the inner class as the Builder. The architecture will be more clear.